# Powershell - Creating the object doesn't detect the constructor

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have created the below class in my C# DLL.

```
public class CustMessage
    {
        CustMessage()
        {
            TimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
      
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }       
    }
```

Now I intend to use this class in my Powershell Session. Hence I now try to load the DLL into my PS Session.

```
$assembly = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("Path_To_My_DLL")

$instance = New-Object MyNameSpace.CustMessage
```

The first statement works perfectly fine. When I execute the next statement i.e. `New-Object MyNameSpace.CustMessage` , it gives me the below error

> New-Object: A constructor was not found. Cannot find an appropriate
> constructor for type MyNameSpace.CustMessage.

When I remove the no-argument constructor from my class, now the statement above works fine. But I wish to use the constructor inside my class.

**How should I change my class OR change the way I use the New-Object so that I am able to create the object even when I have the no-argument constructor present in my class?**

Comment: Can you try to make the constructor `CustMessage` as public

Comment: The constructor is private, which is why it's not accessible. If you remove it then C# compiler will add a default public parameterless constructor and then you can construct the object. Make it public.

Comment: Thanks, Guys abdul and lasse, that was the only problem. Appreciate your quick response,